# android unresolved dependencies error when creating a new project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have updated my Android studio, but after that, I cannot create a new project. My Android version is 2.2 beta 3.

This is an image of the error messages when attempting to create a Gradle sync project:

[image]

Comment: that means android studio is not able to download the library .check your network connection

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same problem, but I have fixed mine by removing this line of code from my Gradle module (app) level:

[image: Remove the blue highlight code]

After removing to sync the project hopefully it will fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the dependencies in gradle **app** as:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
}
```

This worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

1.go to settings

2.select gradle option.

3.uncheck "offline work".

4.rebuild project.

5.that's it. make sure you have a internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the dependencies repositories in Project build.gradle

```
allprojects {
 repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

    "Your dependencies repositorie"

 }
}
```